# How to factorize definition of C# projects (csproj) between platforms (MonoTouch/-Droid/WP7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm planning to develop a distributed application with a mobile part (MonoTouch/MonoDroid/WP7), a desktop part (WPF) and the web part (ASP/Silverlight)...

Of course a good bit of code is shared in more than one platform. Up to now to create 1 project per 1 platform, I took the hitchhiker's way, I've the WPF csproj, let's create a Silverlight one and put the cs file in it. Then I do the same for MonoTouch. Then for MonoDroid. Then for WP7. Is it possible to factorize the content of the csproj in some way? And how to optimize the project creation?

I would not discuss the fact that 1 project per platform is required. What I'm dreaming of is a description which file for which platform in ONE file. Then that file is included in each csproj...

Cheers, Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is great extension that will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921108%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

I am using it for sharing code between MonoDroid, MonoTouch and WP7 project

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for. So my question is answered.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it make sense to place common code into a class library project that you then reference from each of the others?

Comment: In an ideal world where common code is COMMON, it's ok, maybe. But my problem is for the list of compilation units per platform, which isn't necessarily the same. And in the same compilation unit, the code might be platform dependent (#if MONOTOUCH).

Comment: you can't do this, because you can only reference libraries from the same platform (MonoDroid/MonoTouch/WP7)

Comment: you could also add files as "Linked" from an standard .Net project..a few extra steps but if your desktop code is written already it is a one time event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code between several devices I suggest your look at the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), using something like [MonoCross](http://code.google.com/p/monocross/).

As ChrisDB suggested try to share at a level project, not a the file level. Doing the sharing at the project-level will be much easier since:

- many tools (e.g. MonoTouch with MonoDevelop/XCode integration) will be using several files for the UI (a lot of them autogenerated) and you do not want to lose the IDE help for each platform;
- your IDE (VS.NET or MonoDevelop) will be able to keep different options for each project (e.g. defines or custom project options, e.g. MonoTouch);

You might also want to check on the [What contraints should I be aware of to maximize portability of Mono code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645898/what-contraints-should-i-be-aware-of-to-maximize-portability-of-mono-code/7647853#7647853) question / answers since it's a bit similar, but not identical, to your current request.